Autodesk APS DA4I and .Net8
I was wondering if APS DA4I supports .Net 8?
I was playing around with the wrench sample provided by Autodesk and have this working with the .Net Framework (as provided by Autodesk). I've upgraded the DAWrenchConfigPlugin to .Net Core via the upgrade wizard and uploaded the newly compiled appbundle to APS, but now I receive a missing runtime 8.0 exception when running the workitem. I did not change my dataset nor activity.
Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong ?
TIA,
Mark

you are not doing anything wrong. It just does not work at the moment. There is a plan to have this case supported and it is currently being implemented. I can't promise you a specific date when you will be able to use it, but I would be surprised if it would take more then 2 months from now.
Regards, Michal
